# Flask's Jinja nesting some rendered elements in 'strong' elements

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm experiencing a weird behavior with Jinja. I made a dynamic flask route and so I made a jinja modular template, it's just a for loop to create an element for each `article` present in some data (in a dict) I give to Jinja, the template looks like this :

```html
    {% for theme in article_data %}
        {% for article in theme["article"] %}
            {% if article["main"] == 1 %}
            <div style="background-image: url('{{article['content']['image1']}}');" class="theme-item-bg frow space-between">
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="wrapper-row space-between pinkfilter">
            <div class="uB theme-item-text">{{theme["name"]}}</div>
            <div class="pageChanger waves-effect waves-light btn uL primaryB" page="/nos-articles/{{theme['name']}}" title="{{theme['name']}}">Voir plus d'articles</div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

It does work correctly for most of my pages but for one, it have a really weird behavior, Jinja render one of the article correctly and nest the others in a `strong` element.

The data used to render the page have the same structure and is correctly parsed.

Is there a way to prevent Jinja from nesting stuff in a `strong`element?

Comment: It seems unlikely that Jinja would invent elements out of thin air. Are you sure you are running the code you think you are running?

Comment: I am, it does that for other elements (for example when I include my footer template) but it's really bothering me for that one loop because it's breaking the front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be either some html inside `theme["name"]` (fix it by escaping it with `theme["name"]|escape`), or a `<strong>` tag not closed in one your templates.

Jinja doesn’t insert random html tags, but the browsers do when trying to parse and fix a broken html code

Comment: After investigating in the data I was given it appears a `<strong>` is opened but never closed, the `escape` didn't work but removing the opened `<strong>` fixed the problem.